# Image positioning using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem about my code i don't know where or what will i use to fix the problem.

It shows what my code looks like and what i want to be looks like

[image]

As you can see the image above is not tight compare on the image that i want to looks like. How can i make the below picture any idea?

Here is my codes

CSS

```
.img-container {
 height: 500px;
 display: flex;
 }

.img-big {
 background-image: url('/assets/icons/people-crowd-child-kid-large.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 flex: 1;
 }

.img-small {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex: 0 0 50%;
 }

.img-small1 {
 background-image: url('/assets/icons/13-Cuidados-alternativos-en-     familia.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 flex: 50%;
 }

.img-small2 {
 background-image: url('/assets/icons/man-person-cute-young-large.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 flex: 50%;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 img-container">
    <div class="img-big img-responsive"></div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 img-small">
     <div class="img-small1"></div>
     <div class="img-small2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the images up as background images rather than `img` elements? If you want to do it that way, you need to specify a height and width for those elements, otherwise they will be considered 0, which is why you are not seeing them.

Comment: You **must** set height and width on your elements if they're going to be empty like in your example.

Comment: oh really man? can you give me an example with that? let me try it

Comment: Just add height and width to your `.img-small1` class and see if it shows up

Comment: no effect man. trying some other stuff if you have other options please tell me :D

Comment: @Jay where do i will set the height and width ? is it on the class `img-small` or in the `img` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the images as background images, set them up as `img` elements:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 img-container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 img-small">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where do i will declare the height ? i tried on the image itself but no effect. and about the css of <code>img-container</code> and <code>img-small</code> is it not overriding any elements to fit the image? and it give scroll bar to the left how can i get rid of that?

Comment: No need to define height when you do it this way. The height of the image determines the height of the containing element.